# value of variable has changed or not

Tags: javascript

how to find whether a value of variable is changed or not in javascript .

Comment: Do you want to fire something when the value has changed? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ehm?

```
var testVariable = 10;
var oldVar = testVariable;

...
if (oldVar != testVariable)
alert("testVariable has changed!");
```

And no, there is no magical "var.hasChanged()" nor "var.modifyDate()" in Javascript unless you code it yourself.

Comment: I have the same problem, I want to check if the variable was assigned new value even the old value and new value was the same. like: var num1 = 10.... num1 = 10.

Comment: @noyruto88 Default language constructs will not allow you to do this in any way. This is because an assignment operator can be even optimized away by the javascript engine to not overwrite the value if it's exactly the same.

Comment: @noyruto88 The way you can solve this is by creating some kind of "container" class, which wraps the element you need tracked. Something like `var a = Container(5)`. Then to change the value you can do `a.setNewValue(10)` and record internally in the `Container` class the change.

Answer (score 6):

There is a way to watch variables for changes: `Object::watch` - some code below

```
/*
For global scope
*/

// won't work if you use the 'var' keyword
x = 10;

window.watch( "x", function( id, oldVal, newVal ){
    alert( id+' changed from '+oldVal+' to '+newVal );

    // you must return the new value or else the assignment will not work
    // you can change the value of newVal if you like
    return newVal;
});

x = 20; //alerts: x changed from 10 to 20


/*
For a local scope (better as always)
*/
var myObj = {}

//you can watch properties that don't exist yet
myObj.watch( 'p', function( id, oldVal, newVal ) {
    alert( 'the property myObj::'+id+' changed from '+oldVal+' to '+newVal );
});


myObj.p = 'hello'; //alerts: the property myObj::p changed from undefined to hello
myObj.p = 'world'; //alerts: the property myObj::p changed from hello to world

// stop watching
myObj.unwatch('p');
```

Comment: Not supported in IE and Safari.

Answer (score 3):

Using [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set):

```
var _variable;
get variable() {
    return _variable;
}
set variable(value) {
    _variable = value;
    // variable changed
}
```

or if you don't need the value of the variable later:

```
set variable(value) {
    // variable changed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are a firefox user you can check using firebug. If you are using IE we can put alert statements and check the values of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

By comparing it to a known state to see if it differs. If you're looking for something like `variable.hasChanged`, I'm pretty sure that doesn't exist.