# How to watch a variable for changes

Tags: java, variables, reflection

I want to know if there's any way so I could watch for variable value change when the program is running. Of course not using debugger I wanna do it **Programmatically**. For example:

```
class A
{
   public static int valueToBeWatched;
}
```

So at runtime if in any method of any class in my project modifies this value `MyValueChangeListner` event should get called.

Comment: If you can wrap it up with a getter/setter, this would be easy to do. Otherwise, you will have to use a debugger API (which is still programatic, but considerably more complex).

Comment: Lets say a=2, then later in program someone does a=2. Do you want this  sound the alarm too? Or just you use a thread to check variable against the old value periodically?

Comment: can you tell me any debugger API?

Comment: +1 for getter and setter and then call the listener in the setter Have public static variables is essentially a global var. Not good practice

Comment: kindly use `setValueToBeWatched(int value);` and call your `MyValueChangeListner`..

Comment: How can we create a wrapper? Can we wrap an int so it can bu used as an int? There is no operator overloading in java

Comment: you can always compare your old value with the new value passed if you don't want to raise the `Listner`..

Comment: How about overriding Integer's setter&getters?

Comment: Thank you all for replying I am gonna go with AspectJ.

Comment: This is duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401527/how-to-detect-if-a-variable-has-changed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to replace the type `int` with a class which will invoke your listener whenever the values changes.  You might like to ignore setting the value when it hasn't actually changed.

e.g.

```
 private int value;
 private final MyValueChangeListener listener;

 public void setValue(int value) {
    if(this.value == value) return;
    listener.changed(this, this.value, value);
    this.value = value;
 }
```

You can perform this replace using byte code injection, but it is much simple to change the original code.

An alternative is to monitor the value to look for changes periodically. Unless the value changes very slowly you might not see every change. You can use the Debugger API to do this but it not simple and I wouldn't suggest you use it unless you are familiar with the API already.

Java Debugger API Links

http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/toolsapis/jpda/

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/

Comment: Can you provide me any links for Debugger API?

Comment: value = this.value; ? Is that what you mean ?

Answer (score 13):

You cannot. There is no watch-on-modification hook built into Java itself.
Obviously, you could do polling, though. But then it won't be "live".

AspectJ *may* allow such a think, but I'm not sure whether it holds for primitive variables, or only when you are using getters and setters.

The clean Java-way is to make the variable `private` and use getters and setters.

```
private valueToBeWatched;

public void setValue(int newval) {
  valueToBeWatched = newval;
  notifyWatchers();
}

public int getValue() {
  return valueToBeWatched;
}
```

On a side note, avoid `static` whenever possible. In particular `public` but not `final`.

Comment: Found the way using AspectJ .Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use the latest Java SE JDK from Oracle, then I suggest using the **javafx.beans.property** and **javafx.beans.value** APIs.

Here is some basic code:

```
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;

public class ObservableValues
{        

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        DoubleProperty dp = new SimpleDoubleProperty(9);
        dp.addListener( new DoubleChangeListener() );
        dp.setValue(3);
        dp.setValue(6);
    }

    static class DoubleChangeListener implements ChangeListener<Number>
    {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number oldValue, Number newValue) 
        {
            System.out.println("the value has changed from " + oldValue + " to " + newValue);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the output:

the value has changed from 9.0 to 3.0

the value has changed from 3.0 to 6.0

Answer (score 1):

The question, as stated, can be solved by writing an Agent to listen to changes on the provided field (see [fieldWatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#fieldWatch)). The Agent would have to be compiled using a C-calling-compatible language, and invoked on VM start with an `-agentpath:<path-to-agent>=<options>` switch.

A higher-level option is to attach to a running process using [JPDA](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/event/ModificationWatchpointEvent.html)/JDI, which wraps the above call in a (Java) [ModificationWatchpointEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/jpda.html).

Comment: Hey this is looking good.Can you explain me any usage through a sample code.

Comment: No time or interest, sorry. Read the docs or ask again (and be specific in what you need).