# Printing strongly typed Java member variable / field names in error messages

Tags: java, linq, logging, reflection

I want to print the name of the offending class member in my logs. E.g.:

```
Class.Member contains an invalid value.
```

However, I don't want to hardcode `"Class.Member"` as a string in the error message. I want to use the strongly typed name so that it's verified at compile time and refactoring it later is easy.

In .NET it's easy to get the string representation of `Class.Member` using LINQ member expressions. I don't care about the performance since this is usually for a fatal error.

Comment: Show us an example of where you figure out that a value is invalid.

Comment: In Android I try to `resolveAttribute(R.attr.slidingPaneMasterBackground)` at runtime. If it's not found it should crash and log that `slidingPaneMasterBackground` was not found.

Comment: Just curious Are you using a member as public instead of using getters / setters to emulate C# like properties ? Give some code please

Comment: `slidingPaneMasterBackground` is an auto-generated `public int` created by the build tools. I can't change it.

Comment: found a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386604/how-to-watch-a-variable-for-changes