# What is the most efficient way to fire an event when a variable is changed, without modifying the class source code?

Tags: java

I am working with some app code that uses a custom legacy Java library. Unfortunately, I have run across the need to fire an event when a variable (in a library class) is changed. The variables I need to listen to do not have getters and setters, and I do not have access to the original source code.

I have considered using a loop to check variables, although that seems like it would take too many CPU cycles. Another option is a timer, though it doesn't seem like the best option.

According to my research, I cannot use the Observable/Observer functions built into the Java standard library, nor can I use a property change listener because I do not have access to the source code.

What would be the best option in this case? Is there another possibility that I may not be considering?

Comment: AOP. AspectJ is the tool that might help you.

Comment: What is changing the variables?  If it is limited to a few method calls in the legacy class, you could possibly write wrappers for them.  If they change due to external events (that the legacy class listens too) it gets tricky.  However, apparently AspectJ can do this, see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386604/how-to-watch-a-variable-for-changes)

Comment: @bmargulies Thanks for the suggestion about AspectJ, I will look into that!

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by @user949300 would be like:

```
public class Legacy {

    public int value;

}

public class LegacyWrapper {

    private Legacy legacy;

    public LegacyWrapper(Legacy legacy) {
        this.legacy = legacy;
    }


    public void setValue(int newValue){
        legacy.value = newValue;
        notifyChange();
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return legacy.value;
    }
}
```

As said this proxy pattern (relationship between the proxy wrapper and the real subject is at compile time) is only recommended if your legacy objects are changed directly by you, so control over the way (with the setValue method call) it changes is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who suggested AspectJ!
Here is how I was able to do it:

```
public aspect MyAspect
{
    before(int newValue): set(int myVariable) && within(org.example.MyClass) && args(newValue)
    {
        //The value of integer x has changed in class MyClass, fire an event here. 
    }
}

package org.example;
public class MyClass
{
    public int x = 0;
}
```