# Does Java have property observers similar to Swift's willSet & didSet methods?

Tags: java, property-observer

I want to observe whether a variable's value has been changed. I was wondering if Java has something that is equivalent to [the `willSet` and `didSet` methods in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID262)?

Comment: Are you using objects?

Comment: Just variable in general, could be string, int, or instance of classes that I came up with myself.

Comment: Please only tag questions with the language that the question is actually about.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386604/how-to-watch-a-variable-for-changes. Seems like the answer is a no.

Answer (score 6):

Not as a language. Java on its own does not really know properties of any kind. What you can do, though:

1. If the object is yours, just change your setter. That's why they're in the first place.
2. If that is not good enough for you and you want something better, at least I hope you have Java 8. In there, you can use JavaFX's properties: e.g. the [`LongProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/index.html?javafx/beans/property/LongProperty.html).
3. If you can't change the code, you'll have to go for AOP.