# Checking if a field is set to its declared, default value in Java

Tags: java

Let's say that I have a class with a static field with a set default value:

```
public class MyClass {

   public static int numb = 10;

}
```

Now, during program runtime, how would I check if `MyClass`'s `numb` field is set to its default value (in *this* case, `10`)?

From my standpoint, in code, I don't know what the field is set to by default, and I am not the one setting the field, so I can't "simply check if `numb == 10`." I have to be able to check if it is set to exactly what it was declared as in the source code.

Comment: why do you think it is possible to do this?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Well I don't see why it wouldn't be. Assuming that the JVM ditches the original value once the variable changes, I don't see why examining the bytecode or such isn't possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I made this question, I was hoping to get an answer from someone who new about a few methods that reflectively found the value that a variable was initialized to. This kinda seemed like something that reflection would support. But after I posted the question, I realized that there'd be no substantial reason for Java to permanently store the initial value of something in memory.

### Solution

Anyways, I forged a method that reflectively accesses the current value of a variable during runtime, then reads the program's bytecode to check what the variable was when the class was initialized. To do this, it emulates the class's initialization (`<clinit>`) and then simply checks for equality of the variable's current and declared values. (It has a lot of setbacks; see below.)

```
/**
 * Checks if the current value of a variable is the same as the value it was
 * declared as during class initialization. Rules dictating whether or not this
 * method can check for the default value of a given variable are as follows:
 * <ol>
 * <li>The variable must be static.</li>
 * <li>The variable must have been initialized to the value of a constant
 * expression.</li>
 * <li>The variable must be a primitive type.</li>
 * </ol>
 * 
 * @param varName
 *            The name of the variable to be checked. This variable must be
 *            static and belong to the {@link Class}, <code>clas</code>.
 * @param clas
 *            The class of which a static variable, named <code>varName</code>,
 *            belongs.
 * @return <code>true</code> if the specified variable's value as set in the
 *         bytecode is the same as it is when retrieved reflectively at the
 *         beginning of this method call, <code>false</code> otherwise.
 * @throws UnsupportedOperationException
 *             If the specified variable's type is not primitive.
 * @throws SecurityException
 *             As thrown by {@link Class#getDeclaredField(String)} and any other
 *             reflective operation executed by this method.
 * @throws NoSuchFieldException
 *             If attempting to access the field with the given arguments to
 *             this method, throws a {@link NoSuchFieldException}.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *             In case the <code>varName</code> parameter does refer to a field
 *             of the given class, but the field is not static.
 * @throws RuntimeException
 *             In case an unknown or unexpected error occurs.
 * @throws IOException
 *             If an IOException occurs while reading from the
 *             <code>.class</code> file of the specified class.
 */
public static boolean isOriginalValue(String varName, Class<?> clas) throws UnsupportedOperationException,
        NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, RuntimeException, IOException {
    Object currentValue;

    // Check for the current value reflectively:
    Field field = clas.getDeclaredField(varName);
    if (!field.getType().isPrimitive())
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("The specified variable's type is not primitive.");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    try {
        // We pass in null because we assume that the field is static. If it isn't, an
        // IllegalArgumentException is thrown.
        currentValue = field.get(null);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("The current value of the variable could not be accessed.", e);
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Map used to store constant pool values:
    Map<Integer, Object> constants = new HashMap<>();

    // Local classes used to represent certain constant pool items:
    class CPoolClass {
        public CPoolClass(int internalNameIndex) {
        }

    }
    class CPoolNameAndType {
        public final int nameIndex;

        public CPoolNameAndType(int nameIndex, int typeIndex) {
            this.nameIndex = nameIndex;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return (String) constants.get(nameIndex);
        }

    }
    class CPoolField {
        public final int nameAndTypeIndex;

        public CPoolField(int classIndex, int nameAndTypeIndex) {
            this.nameAndTypeIndex = nameAndTypeIndex;
        }

        public CPoolNameAndType getNameAndType() {
            return (CPoolNameAndType) constants.get(nameAndTypeIndex);
        }
    }
    class CPoolString {
        public CPoolString(int stringIndex) {
        }
    }

    // Now to read the bytecode of the class for the original value.
    // First, we open a stream to the .class file of clas.
    DataInputStream reader = new DataInputStream(clas.getResourceAsStream(clas.getSimpleName() + ".class"));

    // A .class file starts with the magic hexadecimal code: 0xCafeBabe.
    if (reader.readInt() != 0xCafeBabe)
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to parse the given class's .class file header.");
    // Next, the file contains four bytes denoting its version.
    reader.readInt();// Read and ditch the four bytes; we don't need them.

    // Parse the constant pool size (2 bytes). We'll go through this many items in
    // the constant pool, and cache the ones we need.
    int constantPoolSize = reader.readShort();

    // Constant pool is of size constantPoolSize-1, so we iterate from 1 to the
    // size.
    for (int i = 1; i < constantPoolSize; i++) {
        byte tag = reader.readByte();
        switch (tag) {
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Could not parse the .class file's constant pool; couldn't determine the initial value of the variable.");
        case 1:// String tag
            constants.put(i, reader.readUTF());
            continue;

        case 3:// Int tag
            constants.put(i, reader.readInt());
            continue;

        case 4:// Float tag
            constants.put(i, reader.readFloat());
            continue;

        case 5:// Long tag
            constants.put(i, reader.readLong());
            i++;
            continue;

        case 6:// Double tag
            constants.put(i, reader.readDouble());
            i++;
            continue;

        case 7:// Class item
            constants.put(i, new CPoolClass(reader.readShort()));
            continue;

        case 8:// Literal String (e.g. "abc", "potato", "a string")
            constants.put(i, new CPoolString(reader.readShort()));
            continue;

        case 9:// Field item
            constants.put(i, new CPoolField(reader.readShort(), reader.readShort()));
            continue;

        case 10:// Method (We don't need to cache this)
        case 11:// Abstract method
            reader.readInt();
            continue;

        case 12:// NameAndType item
            constants.put(i, new CPoolNameAndType(reader.readShort(), reader.readShort()));
            continue;

        case 15:// Method Handle
            reader.readByte();
            reader.readShort();
            continue;

        case 16:// Method Type
            reader.readShort();// Skip 2 bytes
            continue;

        case 18:// Invoke Dynamic
            reader.readInt();
            continue;
        }
    }

    // After the constant pool, there are a few, 2 byte-sized values, a list of
    // interfaces (that the class implements), a list of fields, then the list of
    // methods.
    //
    // We're gonna skip to the methods.

    reader.readInt();// Skip 4 bytes
    reader.readShort();// Skip 2 bytes

    int interfaceListSize = reader.readShort();
    for (int i = 0; i < interfaceListSize; i++)
        reader.readShort();

    int fieldListSize = reader.readShort();
    for (int i = 0; i < fieldListSize; i++) {

        // Skip 6 bytes (total)
        reader.readShort();
        reader.readInt();

        int attributeCount = reader.readShort();
        // Skip through all the attributes.
        for (int j = 0; j < attributeCount; j++) {
            reader.readShort();
            int attributeSize = reader.readInt();
            for (int k = 0; k < attributeSize; k++)
                reader.readByte();
        }

    }

    int methodCount = reader.readShort();

    for (int i = 0; i < methodCount; i++) {

        // Skip the method's modifiers.
        reader.readShort();

        // Static variables are initialized via the <clinit> method, whether or not they
        // are placed in static initialization blocks in the source code. Because of
        // this, we'll have to check the code in this method.
        boolean isClinit = "<clinit>".equals(constants.get((int) reader.readShort()));

        reader.readShort();// Skip over the method descriptor.

        short attributeCount = reader.readShort();

        if (isClinit) {
            // This is the method we want. Iterate over each attribute it has.
            for (int j = 0; j < attributeCount; j++) {
                if ("Code".equals(constants.get((int) reader.readShort()))) {

                    reader.readInt();// Skip over the attribute size. We only need the code table size.
                    reader.readInt();// Skip max stack size and max locals.

                    int codeLength = reader.readInt();

                    // Doubles and longs in the stack will have a null value after them. This
                    // emulates the numbering of an actual stack.
                    Stack<Object> stack = new Stack<Object>() {

                        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                        // Handles the push method
                        @Override
                        public void addElement(Object item) {
                            super.addElement(item);
                            if (item instanceof Double || item instanceof Long)
                                super.addElement(null);
                        }

                        // Handles the add method
                        @Override
                        public synchronized void insertElementAt(Object obj, int index) {
                            if (obj instanceof Double || obj instanceof Long)
                                super.insertElementAt(null, index);
                            super.insertElementAt(obj, index);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public synchronized Object pop() {
                            Object item = super.pop();
                            if (item == null)
                                return super.pop();
                            return item;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public synchronized Object remove(int index) {
                            Object item = super.remove(index);
                            if (item == null)
                                item = super.remove(index - 1);
                            else if (item instanceof Double || item instanceof Long)
                                super.remove(index);
                            return item;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public synchronized Object peek() {
                            Object item = super.peek();
                            if (item == null)
                                return super.get(size() - 2);
                            return item;
                        }

                    };

                    int[] bytes = new int[codeLength];
                    for (int k = 0; k < codeLength; k++)
                        bytes[k] = reader.readUnsignedByte();

                    // Stack<Object> locals = new Stack<>();
                    // If I supported local vars, I'd feel obligated to support arrays here, as
                    // well, and, right now, I don't have enough time for that. Feel free to edit
                    // this question. Otherwise, I may edit this method to support more opcodes
                    // later.

                    Object variable = null;

                    // Here is where we simulate the class's initialization. This process doesn't
                    // handle things like arrays, method calls, or other variables.
                    for (int k = 0; k < codeLength; k++) {
                        // When parsing through mnemonics, we ignore anything that only puts a reference
                        // onto the stack or removes a reference from the stack, since this method only
                        // supports primitive types.

                        switch (bytes[k]) {

                        default:
                            continue;

                        // Pushing

                        case 0x10:// bipush
                            stack.push(bytes[++k]);
                            break;
                        case 0x11:// sipush
                            stack.push((bytes[++k] << 8) + bytes[++k]);
                            break;
                        case 0x12:// ldc
                        case 0x14:// ldc2_w
                            Object item = constants.get((bytes[++k] << 8) + bytes[++k]);
                            if (item instanceof Integer || item instanceof Float || item instanceof Long
                                    || item instanceof Double)
                                stack.push(item);
                            break;

                        // Doubles

                        case 0xe:// dconst_0
                            stack.push((double) 0);
                            break;
                        case 0xf:// dconst_1
                            stack.push((double) 1);
                            break;

                        case 0x63:// dadd
                            stack.push((double) stack.pop() + (double) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x6f:// ddiv
                            stack.push((double) stack.pop() / (double) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x6b:// dmul
                            stack.push((double) stack.pop() * (double) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x77:// dneg
                            stack.push(-(double) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x73:// drem
                            stack.push((double) stack.pop() % (double) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x67:// dsub
                            stack.push((double) stack.pop() - (double) stack.pop());
                            break;

                        case 0x59:// dup
                            stack.push(stack.peek());
                            break;
                        case 0x5a:// dup_x1
                        case 0x5d:// dup2_x1
                            stack.add(stack.size() - 2, stack.peek());
                            break;
                        case 0x5b:// dup_x2
                        case 0x5e:// dup2_x2
                            stack.add(stack.size() - 3, stack.peek());
                            break;

                        // Floats

                        case 0xb:// fconst_0
                            stack.push(0f);
                            break;
                        case 0xc:// fconst_1
                            stack.push(1f);
                            break;
                        case 0xd:// fconst_2
                            stack.push(2f);
                            break;

                        case 0x62:// fadd
                            stack.push((float) stack.pop() + (float) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x6e:// fdiv
                            stack.push((float) stack.pop() / (float) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x6a:// fmul
                            stack.push((float) stack.pop() * (float) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x76:// fneg
                            stack.push(-(float) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x72:// frem
                            stack.push((float) stack.pop() % (float) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x66:// fsub
                            stack.push((float) stack.pop() - (float) stack.pop());
                            break;

                        // Integers

                        case 0x2:// iconst_m1
                            stack.push(-1);
                            break;
                        case 0x3:// iconst_0
                            stack.push(0);
                            break;
                        case 0x4:// iconst1
                            stack.push(1);
                            break;
                        case 0x5:// iconst_2
                            stack.push(2);
                            break;
                        case 0x6:// iconst_3
                            stack.push(3);
                            break;
                        case 0x7:// iconst_4
                            stack.push(4);
                            break;
                        case 0x8:// iconst_5
                            stack.push(5);
                            break;

                        case 0x60:// iadd
                            stack.push((int) stack.pop() + (int) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x7e:// iand
                            stack.push((int) stack.pop() & (int) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x6c:// idiv
                            stack.push((int) stack.pop() / (int) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x68:// imul
                            stack.push((int) stack.pop() * (int) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x74:// ineg
                            stack.push(-(int) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x80:// ior
                            stack.push((int) stack.pop() | (int) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x70:// irem
                            stack.push((int) stack.pop() % (int) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x78:// ishl
                            stack.push((int) stack.pop() << (int) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x7a:// ishr
                            stack.push((int) stack.pop() >> (int) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x64:// isub
                            stack.push((int) stack.pop() - (int) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x7c:// iushr
                            stack.push((int) stack.pop() >>> (int) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x82:// ixor
                            stack.push((int) stack.pop() ^ (int) stack.pop());
                            break;

                        // Longs

                        case 0x9:// lconst_0
                            stack.push(0l);
                            break;
                        case 0xa:// lconst_1
                            stack.push(1l);
                            break;

                        case 0x61:// ladd
                            stack.push((long) stack.pop() + (long) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x7f:// land
                            stack.push((long) stack.pop() & (long) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x6d:// ldiv
                            stack.push((long) stack.pop() / (long) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x69:// lmul
                            stack.push((long) stack.pop() * (long) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x75:// lneg
                            stack.push(-(long) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x81:// lor
                            stack.push((long) stack.pop() | (long) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x71:// lrem
                            stack.push((long) stack.pop() % (long) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x79:// lshl
                            stack.push((long) stack.pop() << (long) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x7b:// lshr
                            stack.push((long) stack.pop() >> (long) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x65:// lsub
                            stack.push((long) stack.pop() - (long) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x7d:// lushr
                            stack.push((long) stack.pop() >>> (long) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x83:// lxor
                            stack.push((long) stack.pop() ^ (long) stack.pop());
                            break;

                        // Stack manipulation

                        // nop is handled by this switch's default case.
                        case 0x58:// pop2
                            stack.pop();
                        case 0x57:// pop
                            stack.pop();
                            break;
                        case 0x5f:// swap
                            Object top = stack.pop(), bottom = stack.pop();
                            stack.push(top);
                            stack.push(bottom);
                            break;

                        // Variable assignment

                        case 0xb3:// putstatic

                            if (varName.equals(((CPoolField) constants.get((bytes[++k] << 8) + bytes[++k]))
                                    .getNameAndType().getName()))
                                variable = stack.pop();
                            break;

                        // Casting

                        case 0x90:// d2f
                            stack.push((float) (double) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x8e:// d2i
                            stack.push((int) (double) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x8f:// dtl
                            stack.push((long) (double) stack.pop());
                            break;

                        case 0x91:// i2b
                            stack.push((byte) (int) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x92:// i2c
                            stack.push((char) (int) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x87:// i2d
                            stack.push((double) (int) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x86:// i2f
                            stack.push((float) (int) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x85:// i2l
                            stack.push((long) (int) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x93:// i2s
                            stack.push((short) (int) stack.pop());
                            break;

                        case 0x8a:// l2d
                            stack.push((double) (long) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x89:// l2f
                            stack.push((float) (long) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x88:// l2i
                            stack.push((int) (long) stack.pop());
                            break;

                        case 0x8d:// f2d
                            stack.push((double) (float) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x8b:// f2i
                            stack.push((int) (float) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x8c:// ftl
                            stack.push((long) (float) stack.pop());
                            break;

                        // Comparisons

                        case 0x98:// dcmpg
                            stack.push((double) stack.pop() > (double) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x96:// fcmpg
                            stack.push((float) stack.pop() > (float) stack.pop());
                            break;

                        case 0x97:// dcmpl
                            stack.push((double) stack.pop() < (double) stack.pop());
                            break;
                        case 0x95:// fcmpl
                            stack.push((float) stack.pop() < (float) stack.pop());
                            break;

                        case 0x94:// lcmp
                            stack.push(((Long) stack.pop()).compareTo((Long) stack.pop()));
                            break;

                        }
                    }

                    return variable.equals(currentValue);

                } else
                    // This isn't the "Code" attribute. Skip it.
                    for (int k = 0; k < reader.readInt(); k++)
                        reader.readByte();

            }
            // If we iterated through each
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Couldn't find the static initialization bytecode for the specified class. Any initial assignments or declarations to the specified variable could not be found.");
        } else {
            // We don't want this method.
            for (int j = 0; j < attributeCount; j++) {
                reader.readShort();// Skip the attribute name. We don't care for this method.
                for (int k = 0; k < reader.readInt(); k++)
                    reader.readByte();// Skip the attribute data.
            }
        }
    }

    throw new RuntimeException("The declared value could not be found");
}
```

This method generally works for variables with simple declared values (e.g. `public static int x = 56;`). There is a large quantity of [opcodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) that it doesn't support, including some that take arguments (so if those opcodes exist in the bytecode of the class, this method won't read them correctly). This method does "work" in extremely simple cases and is more for a proof of concept.

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible with a single field. I would suggest adding a constant to hold the default, and comparing it against `numb` to see if it's changed:

```
private static final int DEFAULT = 10;
public static int numb = DEFAULT;

public static boolean isChanged() {
    return numb != DEFAULT;
}
```

Comment: This would be an optimal solution to my question, especially due to its simplicity, but I do not know what the field is set to by default, and (also from the standpoint of the code in my question), I am not the one setting the field initially. If these were not the case, however, I would definitely accept this answer as correct. I'll try to clarify the complications that I'm facing from the scope of my code, in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Kröw, with your latest clarification of the problem, does the below meet your requirement?

```
public class MyClass {

    public static int numb = 10;
}
public class MyTest {

    private static int default_numb = MyClass.numb;

    public static boolean isChanged() {
        return MyClass.numb != default_numb;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isChanged() + " " + MyClass.numb);
        MyClass.numb = 20;
        System.out.println(isChanged() + " " + MyClass.numb);
        MyClass.numb = 10;
        System.out.println(isChanged() + " " + MyClass.numb);
    }

}
```

The output of running MyTest is:

```
$ java MyTest
false 10
true 20
false 10
```

Comment: To my knowledge, this is the best someone can get without reading bytecode or something else. The only issue that might occur is if `numb` changes before you cache it in `MyTest`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem description says "**From my standpoint, in code, I don't know what the field is set to by default,**"

If the *numb* default value is being provided at runtime, then the following code will accomplish what you are looking for.

```
public class MyClass {

    private static int numb;
    private static int def_numb;
    private static boolean initialized = false; // track numb initialize

    public MyClass(int default_value) {
        if (!initialized) {
            numb = default_value;
            def_numb = numb;
            initialized = true;
        } else {
            numb = default_value;
        }
    }

    public void setNumb(int value) {
        numb = value;
    }

    public int getNumb() {
        return numb;
    }

    public boolean isChanged() {
        return numb != def_numb;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass m2 = new MyClass(5);
        System.out.println(m2.isChanged() + " " + m2.getNumb());
        MyClass m3 = new MyClass(6);
        System.out.println(m2.isChanged() + " " + m2.getNumb());
        System.out.println(m3.isChanged() + " " + m3.getNumb());
        MyClass m4 = new MyClass(5);
        System.out.println(m3.isChanged() + " " + m3.getNumb());
    }
}
```

The following will be displayed by running this program.

```
$ java MyClass
false 5
true 6
true 6
false 5
```

Comment: Since `numb` is static, it is actually initialized when the class, `MyClass`, is loaded, and (in my example) is initialized to a value of ten. Also because it is static, checking its value won't show any difference depending on what object you check it off of. For an example of this, try running the following in your main method:

`MyClass m1 = new MyClass(5);`
`System.out.println(m1.isChanged() + "   " + m1.getNumb());`
`new MyClass(6);`
`System.out.println(m1.isChanged() + "   " + m1.getNumb());`

Comment: Please see the updated program (edited just now) that fixes the issue that you correctly identified. I have added your example to  test the code. Hope this helps!

Comment: Kröw, you indicate "I am not the one setting the field initially", in effect your requirement is that the default value is not known at compilation time but obtained at runtime. My updated program meets this requirement and also adds the test case that you proposed. Please take a look and comment on the updated code above.Thanks!

Comment: I did indicate what you specified, but (as shown from the code in my question), the value is set and known during compilation time (`... int numb = 10;`). I'll try to clarify my question a bit more to better indicate this.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any idea of the default value, you should track the variable for any changes. Since it is a public and static variable i do not think it is possible. However, you can change your solution as suggested in the below. 
Use `MyValueChangeListener` or Java debugger API

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386604/how-to-watch-a-variable-for-changes)