# How can I watch for changes on class variables?

Tags: java

My project has requirement to know whether use change data or not but I'm not allowed to modify data model itself. For example, I have class like this:

```
public class Person {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    Address address;
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public Address getAddress() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address= address;
    }

}
```

And it should always be POJO like this, i can't invoke any other methods in getter/setter, so that there is some solutions but it's not fit with my requirement:

- [How to detect if a variable has changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401527/how-to-detect-if-a-variable-has-changed)
- [How to watch a variable for changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386604/how-to-watch-a-variable-for-changes)
- [How to create change listener for variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433855/how-to-create-change-listener-for-variable)

I also can not apply Observer Pattern here.

My current solution is: after I initialize the person instance, I parse it to JSON and create a hash (MD5), whenever I want to check changes, I do that logic again and compare the new hash with old one. If it's not the same, that mean my data has changed. Somehow it works fine, but I'm still worried about it, not sure it's good way or not.

Comment: Why can't you simply use `==` comparison?

Comment: You state a vague objective and then eliminate all the usual methods to accomplish that objective.  It would help if you would start out by explaining the high-level business case that makes this necessary.

Comment: You also indicate that what you have works... so it is unclear what you're really asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on some factor:

Is POJO serializable / implements hashCode / equals?
You can clone your object and check equals

Can you change reference of Object?
You can extends your object class and add some checks in methods.

For serialization to JSON you can use GSON lib:
https://github.com/google/gson from google. After that you can check string equals

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.1

Comment: hi @Martinus_
yes, i can change reference so i can't compare by object. your solution is similar with me. thanks for help

Comment: So if you can change reference you can make delegate from your variable and override set methods with check and after super.method(). You can also use Mockito.spy for it (I'm not sure if it is a good idea to use Mockito in production code) but Mockito will do delegate for you. (Mockito.spy / and after that verify)