# Check if variable has changed for the first time and is a bigger number than the previous var javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

So I have this little code:

```
    var previousImgFileSize;
var loadedGl = setInterval(function(){  
var data_url = renderergl.domElement.toDataURL();
var head = 'data:image/png;base64,';
var imgFileSize = Math.round((data_url.length - head.length)*3/4) ;
var logit = console.log(imgFileSize);
if (imgFileSize != previousImgFileSize && previousImgFileSize){
    alert("Ready");
}
previousImgFileSize=imgFileSize;
}, 100);
```

What I want to do is check if the var imgFileSize has changed so if I run the above code it will output a particular number but later on when another image loads it will change the var value to another number I want to listen/check to when that happens how would I go about this?

It's a `<canvas>` powered by three.js which is creating a black screenshot every second or so so the first image is always the same size when no content is yet loaded in the `<canvas>` because it's a black/blank image when the canvas has loaded and displayed the 3d models then the data image changes to a screenshot of the scene every second again (the 2nd image) but the second image is bigger in file size because it has colors and isn't just black...that's what I am trying to capture.the first time the file size changes...

the above code doesn't update the var when the file changes it straight away infact I have to rotate the scene a couple of times before it then captures the var ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [value of variable has changed or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051114/value-of-variable-has-changed-or-not)

Comment: @Mugen87 No I already have that